# Selenium: How to combine parameter and text

Tags: selenium-ide

*I need to verify a text, include two strings, exp: 2013-01-09 00:00:00.0, this text in a table.
but, I want to verify '2013-01-09' only, **this text was stored by a parameter named EndDate**.
I use selenium IDE to target the text, result below:*

```
>Command: verifyText
>
>Target: //tr[@id='o-tr-encounter_id_94576']/td[3]
>
>Value: 2013-01-09 00:00:00.0
```

*So, **I want to combine EndDate and '00:00:00.0' in Value if possible.**
Please help me.
Thanks for your care.*

Answer (score 0):

this will work accept the answer if its work for you

```
<tr>
<td>store</td>
<td>${endtime} 00:00:00.0</td>
<td>p</td>
```

`<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${p}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>`